# How do I control the amount of links in the homepage feature?

Tags: ee2

My website currently has 5 links that rotate in a slide gallery on the homepage. I can edit these links by editing the Homepage feature but I don't know how to reduce their number from 5 to 4 links being displayed. Does anyone know how to adjust this?

Thank you

Comment: A code example from the template/snippet that outputs the gallery would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

By adding limit parameter to your EE code you will limit the results. For more details please see 
[documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#limit)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your homepage feature is actually built, but in most cases, you can simple add something like the following:

limit="4"

This "limit" feature is built into EE (see URL below), but most modules/extensions such as Matrix, Playa, etc all use it as well.

Documentation:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#limit

If that does not work, please provide a sample of the code and I can help guide you further to get it fixed up.